# How to ignore empty cells when using set.Values() from .getValues()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a script that gets all values from a row the user specifies. Then I fill in these values in a new sheet and automatically go one row down to set the next value. However some cells are empty and I want to ignore these. At the moment my script goes down a row each time it writes a value, but it does this also for empty values.

```
function tourzettelV4() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ppt2019 = app.getSheetByName("PlakatTool2019");

  // Abfragen aus welcher Zeile der Tourzettel generiert werden soll
  // Asking which row to use

  var row=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Gib die Zeile mit dem Datum für die Tour ein').getResponseText();

  var dateTour = ppt2019.getRange(row, 1).getValue();

  var newSheet = app.getSheetByName("TourzettelV2")
  newSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(dateTour);


  newSheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue("Gebiet:");
  newSheet.getRange(3, 1).setValue("Was");
  newSheet.getRange(3, 2).setValue("Format");
  newSheet.getRange(3, 3).setValue("Menge");
  newSheet.getRange(3, 4).setValue("Info");


 var lastCol = ppt2019.getLastColumn();

    // Loop mit if value empty repeat loop, else set value

 var checkCol = 3;
 var mengeZeile = 4;

  for(var komulierer = 0; komulierer < lastCol - 3; komulierer++){
    var plakatMenge = ppt2019.getRange(row, 3 + komulierer, checkCol + komulierer, row).getValues();


    if(plakatMenge === ""){
          }
//this is where I want to just repeat the loop in case a cell is empty

    else {

    newSheet.getRange(mengeZeile, 3).setValue(plakatMenge);
    mengeZeile = mengeZeile + 1;
    }
  }  
}
```

I fiddled around with .isBLank(), which didn't work and I tried to use an if else statement so that if a value is empty it just restarts the loop and only if it is not empty it sets the value, which didn't work.

So at the moment is looks like this:

```
EMPTY
10
EMPTY
EMPTY
20
```

But I need it like this:

```
10
20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

Your `if` statement is referencing the **WHOLE** array, not just an individual object. This is why it's always returning `true` and setting all of the values.

---

#### Modifications:

```
if (plakatMenge[komulierer][0]) {
  newSheet.getRange(mengeZeile, 3).setValue(plakatMenge[komulierer][0]);
  mengeZeile = mengeZeile + 1;
}
```

This `if` statement now checks if the first object in that row of the array is not empty then writes the line it finds to your sheet.

Using this script means you can get rid of your `if else` and just use an `if` statement instead.

---

#### References:

- [JavaScript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Hey, thanks. I get an error for .setValues(plakatMenge[komulierer]); "cannot convert array to object[][]" Sorry if this is something obvious, I am still learning.

Comment: Sorry about that - I've updated that part of the answer. Could you review and try again?